# Is there any way to access the video file path that converted to Uint8List

Tags: flutter, dart, uint8list

In the below code of [flutter_material_pickers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_material_pickers/example) plugin, I want to get the video file path but the returned **file** variable of showMaterialFilePicker function is Uint8List type.

```
 void onTap() {
    if (value == null) {
      showMaterialFilePicker(
        fileType: Filetype.video,
        onChanged: (file) => setState(() {
          didChange(file);
          if (widget.onChanged != null) widget.onChanged(file);
        }),
      );
    } else {
      _showUnattachDialog();
    }
  }
```

Refer to this function of flutter_material_pickers, The code is:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// Allows selection of a file.
Future<void> showMaterialFilePicker({
  BuildContext context,
  FileType fileType = FileType.image,
  String fileExtension,
  ValueChanged<Uint8List> onChanged,
}) async {
  try {
    File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: fileType);
    var data = file.readAsBytesSync();
    if (onChanged != null && file != null) onChanged(data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.runtimeType is PlatformException) return; // user clicked twice
    if (error.runtimeType is NoSuchMethodError) return; // user canceled dialog
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option to read path from `Uint8List`. This type stores only byte data. You can even test it by comparing results of `readAsBytes()` from two equal images in different locations.

You can use [file_picker](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker) (this package is used in *flutter_material_pickers* as well) and get `File` as in [*Usage*](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/#usage) section and from `File` you have access to the path.